# Cyrillic content In mysql is seen like: ÑÐ°Ñ†Ð´Ð°ÑÑ†Ð´

Tags: php, mysql

Hello there :) I have a problem about my mysql database where i want to store Cyrillic content, but unfortunately it is stored like  ÑÐ°Ñ†Ð´Ð°ÑÑ†Ð´ in my database. I have my connect.php :

```
      header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); 
      mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');
      $host = "localhost";
      $username = "root";
      $password = "";
      $db = "cdcol";

      mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die(mysql_error());
      mysql_select_db($db);
```

I have database utf8_unicode_ci collation... Read about this problem in many places but couldn't find a solution. Can anybody help me ?

Comment: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: For starters, you're setting the connection encoding before you make a connection...

Comment: Ok but i still can't get it